# problema con la funcionalidad de un codigo

Tags: c

en la universidad me dieron un ejercicio para hacer.
dandome el siguiente codigo:

```
int main (){

    int i, j, valor1 = 0, valor2 = 0, valor3 = 1;

    for (j = 0 ; j < iter ; j++){
        for (i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
            valor1 = valor1 + 1;
        for (i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
            valor2 = valor2 - 1;
        for (i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
            valor3 = valor3 * 1;
    }

    if (i == 0){
        j = 0;
    }else{
        i = 2 + 3;
    }

    while (i > 0){
        j ++;
        valor2 = valor2 +1;
        i--;
        valor1 = valor2 + valor3;
        valor1 = valor2 + valor3;
        valor3 = valor2 - valor3;
        j --;
    }

    printf ("valor1: %d\n",valor1);
    printf ("valor2: %d\n",valor2);
    printf ("valor3: %d\n",valor3);
```

me pide que debo cambiarlo y optimizarlo pero no encuentro ninguna forma para hacerlo..... este es el codigo que estoy haciendo yo:

```
int main (){

    int j = 0, valor1 = 0, valor2 = 0, valor3 = 1, i = 0, n;

    while (j < 5){
            j++;
            n = 0;
        do {
            n ++;
            valor1 = valor1 + n;
            valor2 = valor2 - n;
            valor3 = valor3 * n;
        }while (n < 3);
    }
    while (i < 5){
        i ++;
        valor2 = valor2 + 1;
        valor1 = valor2 + valor3;
        valor1 = valor2 + valor3;
        valor3 = valor2 - valor3;
    }

    printf ("valor1: %d\n",valor1);
    printf ("valor2: %d\n",valor2);
    printf ("valor3: %d\n",valor3);
```

uno de los puntos seria descartar aquellas sentencias que estan de mas, y reducir con otras sentencias las que esten muy largas para ahorrar tiempo a la hora de codificar.

estoy intentando aplicar casi la misma logica con un while y un do - while, pero sigue sin funcionar, mi principal pregunta es si en el for de el codigo dado los valores de las variables se resetean cuando j aumenta su valor con el ++

si alguien me puede ayudar seria de gran ayuda, desde ya gracias!!

Comment: Los valores de las variables declaradas no se reinician porque una estructura de control haga un ciclo más. La variable es un espacio de memoria y su valor no cambia a menos que tú así lo indiques. Sólo reasignando un valor dentro del while, una variable se va a _resetear_

Comment: Ahora, los for anidados del principio pueden ser sólo un par de for anidados y, dentro del segundo, hacer las tres asignaciones. No uses estructuras while sólo por usarlas. Y lo último: en el código de ejemplo hay una variable iter que no está definida. Es decir, nos estás mostrando código que no compila :/